# Strange grep filter issue on one server but not another

Tags: bash, curl, elasticsearch, awk, grep

**Two Systems:**

Working: Linux Mint

Not Working: CentOS

**Issue Description:**

When running CURL to filter a CURL call to a ES sever, the filter works when run on from localhost (Linux Mint) but not from remote server.
Strangely, the remote server (CentOS) is able to filter for other indices, just not the one in question. Furthermore, deleting the index and recreating it, allows it to be filtered from the remote server (CentOS).

**All Indices:**

```
[root@VMW ~]# curl '172.21.34.231:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.25     LSf3mVWkRVaggPDQcwkU8w   1   1     224455          844    113.3mb        113.3mb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.26 CEh7jW_GTyeam6_as5Fa7g   1   1      17276            0      3.5mb          3.5mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.27     wbg18DtuTBiqiIJLRDvfcQ   1   1     270408          606    142.3mb        142.3mb
yellow open   hnsdevices                      cMvivPjMTSqJSiO_d6bHDA   5   1     238116            0    193.2mb        193.2mb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.25 -R4CoU13QdqNuERe1AVH5w   1   1      17277            0      3.5mb          3.5mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.28     SaYCov1wR4acpODxlilRGg   1   1     285810          658    147.4mb        147.4mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.30     fyHjHN0MSHiJS9_kpmSNkw   1   1     187548          792     96.3mb         96.3mb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.24 qRt0BxZrTtyMHs0kPumHXQ   1   1      17274            0      3.5mb          3.5mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.24     1bdo--KHTii-qMOyqSGUlQ   1   1     218730          744    109.7mb        109.7mb
yellow open   .monitoring-data-2              KSZXodCPTlGSmSlgNtZqRA   1   1          3            0     13.7kb         13.7kb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.27 5HqT9-5nSBCWWpfGXfHKZw   1   1      17274            0      3.5mb          3.5mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.26     alAd4NscRSisgG03pFVKFQ   1   1     254943         1018    135.4mb        135.4mb
yellow open   historicalalerts                594jQoVJRaKZ_5DpS2pO4w   5   1      92790            0      110mb          110mb
yellow open   alerts                          FtfNq4DEQdehTl7ziSgOpw   5   1       1087            0      1.3mb          1.3mb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.30 ZGC96KgOTuOwE9zJiDpIWQ   1   1      11442            0      2.4mb          2.4mb
yellow open   eit-alertsv1                    ezvv8SvmRCuAmSZFyiPOWg   5   1       4824            0      5.8mb          5.8mb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.28 hpnCzgcESm6Kv6neEEaTpw   1   1      17276            0      3.3mb          3.3mb
yellow open   .monitoring-es-2-2017.01.29     ghgOsujkT-SXxiB_H3ZJZg   1   1     248095          576    132.8mb        132.8mb
yellow open   .kibana                         1q8wt2STTd-O5wrxwsuYzQ   1   1          3            0     24.5kb         24.5kb
yellow open   .monitoring-kibana-2-2017.01.29 TIYSfQg-QviEzjKt5_iEAQ   1   1      17277            0      3.4mb          3.4mb
```

**Broken Grep on CentOS**

```
[root@VMW ~]# curl '172.21.34.231:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty' 2>&1 | grep eit | awk '{print $3}'
[root@VMW ~]#
```

**Working Grep on CentOS for another Index**

```
[root@VMW ~]# curl '172.27.30.231:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty' 2>&1 | grep hnsdevices | awk '{print $3}'
hnsdevices
```

**Working Grep on Mint**

```
mhassan@mhassan-virtual-machine ~ $ curl '172.21.34.231:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty' 2>&1 | grep eit | awk '{print $3}'
eit-alertsv1
```

It is puzzling why only filtering for that particular index fails, while working from another server and can be corrected by deleting and recreating that particular index.

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you also show what is your grep version in both cases? That is, show the output of `grep --version`.

Comment: @fedorqui `CentOS: grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` `Mint: grep (GNU grep) 2.16`
What is most puzzling is that CentOS seems to filter just fine for another index as show above, but not the one in question. Issue with Index? Since, deleting and recreating it allows it to be filtered from the CentOS box

Comment: I'd suggest to run `curl ··· | grep alertsv1 | od -tx1 -tc` in both CentOS and Mint and compare the outputs.

Comment: Not a fix for this but to avoid false match problems do `awk '$3~/^eit/{print $3}'` instead of `grep eit | awk '{print $3}'`. What happens if you redirect the curl output to a file and THEN run your grep on it? If you `vi` the output on CentOS can you see lines that contain `eit`?

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton! Do you mind explaining what is happening in the `awk` statement that you descried and why it avoids false matching problems? I redirected the output to `test.txt` and was able to grep accordingly `[root@VMW ~]# cat test.txt | grep eit | awk '{print $3}'
eit-alertsv1`

Comment: grep doesn't know about fields so `grep eit` looks for `eit` anywhere on the line. You instead only want to find `eit` at the start of the 3rd field and that's what `awk '$3~/^eit/` does. When you do `cmd | cmd | cmd` buffering can become more of an issue than just `cmd | cmd` so I suspect `curl | awk` will work where `curl | grep | awk` is failing due to grep buffering it's output since it's not writing to a tty.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @EdMorton. It however did not fix the anomaly. I instead decided to write to a file and `grep` on that. Thank you everyone who gave suggestions!